# \begin{equation}f(x,y) =\begin{cases}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}}{\ln(x^2+y^2)},&\text{(x,y)$\neq$ (0,0)}\\0,&\text{(x,y)=(0,0)}\end{cases}\end{equation}

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A function:

\begin{equation}
  f(x,y) =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}}{\ln(x^2+y^2)}, & \text{(x,y) $\neq$ (0,0)}\\
      0, & \text{(x,y) = (0,0)}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

is given. Task is to check:

$1.$ Continuity of $f$

$2.$ Existence of directional derivative at any direction at point $(0,0)$

$3.$ Existence of partial derivatives at point $(0,0)$, and if they exist to calculate the value

$4.$ Differentiability of $f$

This is how I tried solving it:

$1.$ When I replace x and y with zeroes I get $\frac{0}{-\infty}$ which is $0$, so limit is zero and function is continuous

$2.$ I chose direction $u=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ and tried solving limit:

Also when I am free to chose direction which one would you chose, my professor usually goes with this one..
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(0+t\cos\alpha,0+t\sin\alpha)-f(0,0)}{t}=..=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{t}\ln(t^2)}
$$
here I got stuck..

$3.$ When checking existence of partial derivatives , precisely limits I get the same limit expression as in $2.$ so also got stuck there

$4.$ since I haven't shown existence of partials I couldn't continue to differentiability ...

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using L'Hôpital's rule, one obtains
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \sqrt[3]{t}\ln(t^2)=
\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln(t^2)}{1/\sqrt[3]{t}}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{2t/t^2}{-\frac13{t}^{-4/3}}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{-6t}{{t}^{2/3}}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow0} (-6t^{1/3})= 0;
$$
thus,
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{t}\ln(t^2)}= \infty.
$$
($\infty$ is not $+\infty$ here, see the comments below)

Hence, the directional and partial derivatives are infinite and the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @ Infinity_hunter The limit is just $\infty$, without a sign: $\forall \epsilon >0 \;\exists \delta>0:\; \forall t:\; 0<|t|<\delta\; |f(t)|>\epsilon$.

Comment: @ Infinity_hunter No. See the "Alternative notation" section of that Wikipedia article. As for me, this is the first time I come across this concept of infinity, all the authors I read before used the "Alternative notation". But I have added the comment anyway